# preloading a dynamic classes which loads its own content

Tags: actionscript-3, preload

How do you preload dynamic classes which loads its own content? cause theoretically speaking the classes doesn't have a size yet until it loads its content right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you would have to initialise the object, start it loading and then get the size of the file(s) from it to do a preload animation. therefore you cannot preload an uninitialised class as you dont know the size of it untill it is loading.

Comment: Even Adobe's built-in preloader classes needs to "guess" at the size of the stuff it's preloading. So there really is no way. Instead of showing a bar with percent and stuff, just show a generic loading bar...